# Как в Visual C++ в Visual Studio 2015 использовать регистры xmm8-xmm15? или как настроить компилятор так, чтобы он позволял их использовать?

Tags: visual-c++, ассемблер

Здравствуйте, у меня проблема с использованием регистров xmm8-xmm15, при попытке использование, студия выдаёт ошибку, в вывод пишет "недопустимый тип операнда" и ссылается на строку где используются эти регистры. (Процессор поддерживает AVX)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<immintrin.h>
#include<cstdlib>
int main(){
char* Bytes = "We're just bytes for xmm registers!!!";
_asm{
    mov eax, Bytes;
    movups xmm1, [eax];
    movups xmm7, [eax];
    movups xmm8, [eax];
}
float *first_array = new float[8]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
float *second_array = new float[8]{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
__m256 first=_mm256_loadu_ps(first_array), second=_mm256_loadu_ps(second_array);
first = _mm256_add_ps(first, second);
_mm256_storeu_ps(first_array, first);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    printf(" %.1f", *(first_array++));
}
printf("\n");
system("pause");
return 0;}
```

А вот эта версия кода при компиляции не выдаёт ошибок (и работает как должна):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<immintrin.h>
#include<cstdlib>
int main(){
char* Bytes = "We're just bytes for xmm registers!!!";
_asm{
    mov eax, Bytes;
    movups xmm1, [eax];
    movups xmm7, [eax];
}
float *first_array = new float[8]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
float *second_array = new float[8]{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
__m256 first=_mm256_loadu_ps(first_array), second=_mm256_loadu_ps(second_array);
first = _mm256_add_ps(first, second);
_mm256_storeu_ps(first_array, first);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    printf(" %.1f", *(first_array++));
}
printf("\n");
system("pause");
return 0;}
```

Не знаю как настроить Visual Studio 2015 чтобы позволяла использовать регистры xmm8-xmm15, а не только xmm0-xmm7.

Answer (score 1):

Укажите [архитектуру процессора](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx), например `/arch:AVX`.

Comment: "Включить расширенный набор инструкций"  устанавливал и "Расширения Advanced Vector Extensions (/arch:AVX)", и "Advanced Vector Extensions 2 (/arch:AVX2)" выдают туже ошибку.